# Convert decimal to unsigned decimal (or string?) in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimal, uint64

I have a variable, `DifferenceAmt`, which is a decimal. It can be either negative or positive. I need to output the value of `DifferenceAmt`, but without the negative sign if it's negative, as a string. I know how to delete the negative sign by checking first if `DifferenceAmt` is less than zero, and then doing a substring from the 2nd character if it is, but this seems cumbersome. I've tried converting `DifferenceAmt` to a UInt64 first,

```
UInt64 differenceamt = (UInt64)DifferenceAmt;
```

but I keep getting an error message that the number is too big for a UInt64 (even when it's -10, for example). How can I do this?

Comment: `Math.Abs(DifferenceAmt)`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you Ulugbek! If you post this as an answer, I'll up-vote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple available ways to do it.
The simplest way is to use absolute value using [Math.Abs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs.aspx).

```
decimal x = -10.53m;
string s = Math.Abs(x).ToString(); // 10.53
```

Another way is to use custom [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) with empty [NegativeSign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativesign.aspx).

```
decimal x = -10.53m;
string s = x.ToString(new NumberFormatInfo { NegativeSign = string.Empty }); // 10.53
```

One more way is to use custom formatter for positive/negative numbers. But you have to specify custom string format in such case. More on this: [The ";" Section Separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator).

```
decimal x = -10.53m;
string s = x.ToString("#.##;#.##") // 10.53
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Math.Abs(differenceAmt)` to get the absolute value.

Casting to `UInt64` won't work. Your example of -10 is outside the range of `UInt64`, and it would similarly fail for other `Decimal` values outside the range of UInt64. It would also have to truncate the value to an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Math.Abs(DifferenceAmt).ToString();` This will give you the absolute value of the number and remove the negative sign.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
Math.Abs(differenceAmt).ToString();
```

see this:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ke8e73(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ke8e73%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This isn't `C#` code... I have done your job for you and edited the post.

Comment: @user3359388 - it wasn't valid code before Brandon's edit.  Capitalization matters!

Comment: Indeed, capitalization is very very important in C#.